# Открытие сайта на wordpress после переноса на удалённые хостинг перенаправляет на локальный домен

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Файлы темы перенес напрямую (тема самописная), базу переносил через скрипт Search-Replace-DB-master, в консоль войти получается, данные из базы отображаются, а вот при попытке зайти на сайт перебрасывает на локальный домен (выдаёт ошибку, так как локальный сервер отключен).

Пробовал чистить кэш браузера, кэш wp, не помогло. На другом компе открывается всё как положено, что это может быть?

Comment: А в настройках WP url то поменяли?

Comment: Надо чистить историю браузера https://monosnap.com/file/1AG1n4qXxELuucK1HUOdng16eASGJq

Comment: И историю браузера чистил, и в wp и в настройках и в базе url на новый заменил

Comment: @Вадим а если на хостинге index.php временно переименовать например на __index.php и создать свой с кодом например `<?php echo 'OK'; ?>` то OK отображается?

Comment: @stckvrw нет, он сразу перебрасывает на старый домен

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу еще содержание своего .htaccess

Comment: .htaccess файл родной без изменений в корневой папке, в папке с темой его нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

Перенос у WP порой не тривиален.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

Посмотрите, чему у вас в базе равен url сайта.

```
SELECT * from wp_options where option_name='siteurl' or option_name='home';
```

Вполне вероятно, что там `localhost` и стоит. Если так, то попробуйте поменять на нужный домен:

```
update wp_options set option_value='ваш_домен_сайта' where option_name='siteurl' or option_name='home';
```

Только бекап базы сделайте на всякий случай.

Хотя, если на другом компе всё норм, то, скорей всего, что-то с DNS. Вы, случаем, в **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** ничего не прописывали? Если да, то уберите. Если ничего не прописывали, то попробуйте прописать там временно, пока кеш DNS не отпустит:

```
ip_сервера ваш_домен
```

Comment: Интересно [высказался](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516783/3208225) главный разработчик WP: "an absolute URL is ironically more portable". Типа: "Вы чаще будете перемещать WP в субдиректорию и это важно, нежели с локалки на хостинг"

Comment: @stckvrw каждый раз, когда нужно переносить WP сайт куда-нить, запасаюсь корвалолом :D

Comment: @Suvitruf все как вы написали, было сделано, но ничего не помогло. При вводе нового url сразу перебрасывает на старый(локальный)

Comment: @Вадим а прописать айпи и домен в файле hosts тоже пробовали?

Comment: @stckvrw вариант с host еще не пробовал

Comment: вариант с файлом host не дал результата

Comment: Видимо дело в браузере, так как через IE зашел, и все отображается. Но что с ним не так не понятно

Comment: @Suvitruf там все тривиально, как шлагбаум. Если пользоваться инструментами для переноса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220. Ежедневно таскаем сайты туда-сюда, без попкорна )